# Forma rápida de determinar que un registro no existe en una tabla

Tags: sql, oracle

Mantengo una aplicación web bastante antigua y que opera con tablas bastante grandes (70 columnas y +60 millones de registros). En dicha aplicación se permite borrar ciertos elementos, por ejemplo una línea de autobús, si estos elementos no tienen operaciones asociadas. Aquí es donde viene el problema. Si, por ejemplo, se crea una nueva línea de autobús con algún error y se quiere borrar, el proceso de borrado lo primero que hace es la siguiente perla:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) OPERATIONS FROM
(
    SELECT LINE_ID from validations where LINE_ID = 1259299
)
```

Como la línea acaba de ser creada, no existen operaciones; esta query se patea toda la tabla, sus más de sesenta millones de registros, buscando algo que no existe. Virtualmente la query no tiene final, al menos de cara al usuario. La tabla está particionada por empresa (atm) y fecha (operationdate), pero en la query solo podría usar la empresa dado que si pongo un rango de tiempo puedo caer en borrar una línea que tiene operaciones muy separadas en el tiempo. Solo hay 3 empresas principales, por lo que el uso de esta partición no ahorra demasiado tiempo. El campo por el que se filtra, LINE_ID no es un índice porque tiene bastante variabilidad.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) OPERATIONS FROM
(
    SELECT LINE_ID from validations where LINE_ID = 1259299 and atm=103
)
```

He probado una [variante](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9527967800346138830) usando `sample block` que ha finalizado en 94 segundos. El problema que tiene es que coge un bloque de registros al azar para dar una "aproximación", con lo cual no sirve.

```
select 10 * count(*) from validations sample block (10) where LINE_ID = 1259299;
```

Además también he probado con EXISTS, tampoco parece terminar, al menos no en un tiempo razonable.

```
select 'Y' from dual where exists (select log_id from validations where LINE_ID = 1259299 and atm=103);
```

En resumen, busco una manera rápida de comprobar si un registro con el filtro de LINE_ID y ATM NO existe en la tabla. ¿Alguna idea?. Gracias.

Comment: ¿Existe un índice en esas columnas? Si se crea el índice no debería de recorrer toda la tabla y el `EXISTS()` debería ser casi inmediato.

Comment: No, no existe índice. Crearlos es la primera solución que se me ocurrió, pero para unas tablas tan grandes la creación podría ser bloqueante y no soy el DBA. Dado que el borrado de entidades es algo muy poco frecuente, parece que no están muy dispuestos a que se creen índices.

Comment: Rafa, cuando no hay indices involucrados en las busquedas el manejador termina recorriendo toda la tabla.

Comment: Eso me temo, no he encontrado más posibles soluciones, pero quería consultarlo por aquí por si se me escapa algo o había alguna técnica que no conociese. Gracias de todas formas.

Comment: "...El campo por el que se filtra, LINE_ID no es un índice porque tiene bastante variabilidad" --- ¿Cómo? Basta con crear el índice y tu consulta sería instantánea, aunque la table tenga 60 millones de filas. No veo el problema.

Answer (score 1):

Un simple índice con ambas columnas hará que tu consulta sea prácticamente instantánea. Agrega el índice:

```
create index ix1 on validations (line_id, atm);
```

o, si consideras que `atm` es más selectiva:

```
create index ix1 on validations (atm, line_id);
```

Crear un índice con 60 millones de filas podría demorar un par de horas. En todo case son sólo dos columnas pequeñas; debería ser relativamente rápido. Yo recomendaría hacerlo en la noche después de horas de oficina. No debería ser bloqueante, en cualquier caso.

Con este índice, la consulta sería más o menos instantánea si la cantidad de filas encontradas es baja (menos de 10000).

```
select count(*)
from validations 
where line_id = 1259299 and atm = 103
```

Ahora bien, si la cantidad potencial de filas es masiva (más de 100000) tal vez no sea necesario contar exactamente las filas, sino que tan sólo saber si hay o no hay. Para esto la siguiente consulta es aún más rápida:

```
select line_id
from validations 
where line_id = 1259299 and atm = 103
fetch next 1 rows only
```

Esta consulta no entrega ninguna fila cuando no hay filas que cumplan con el criterio, o una fila (cualquiera) cuando las hay; haya una fila o un millón de filas que cumplen con el criterio, sólo entrega una fila. La ventaja es que es mucho más veloz.

Comment: @RafaJ ¿Y, funciona? Pregunto de pura curiosidad...